Shell script: Any possible to create a json object by variable key and value pair
I'm trying to create a json object by given key/value pair with variable format in shell script under Linux.bash 5.2.21
new_json_object=$(cat last_sms.json | jq '. += {($key) : "$value"}')
echo $new_json_object | jq '.'

and shell throws
jq: error: $key is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
. += {($key) : "$value"}       
jq: 1 compile error

I did not find much advice from internet, seems jq not support create json object by variable key? Or how I can define a key with variable name?
Please advise!

What is the form of your input, and what overall output do you expect? Are key and value supposed to be shell variables?

Try jq --arg key "$key" --arg value "$value" '.[$key] = $value' last_sms.json

@Ry- yes, it is shell variables.

@pmf. Thank you for your advice. I had found out how to do it. Please see my updated.

Don't change the question.  It invalidates the advise given.  Only revise it to clarify the question or to supply new informationt. Do post an answer if pmf is not writing one up for you.

If you found a solution you should post it as an answer below, not in the question.
